# Show Results of accuracy function in tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api, forecasting

I'm using the code below to forecast with r in tableau.  I'm appending the 20 hour forecast on to the end of a year of SaleCount data.

I would like to also be able to show the accuracy of the forecast.

I would like to be able to show the results of the accuracy function from r, for example:

```
fcastAccuracy<-accuracy(fcast, tsTest)
fcastAccuracy[2,2] ##RMSE
```

in tableau, maybe as a text table or as a tooltip when you hover over the forecast on the visualization.

Does anyone know how to show the accuracy of a forecast in tableau either visually, or just by displaying say the RMSE value from accuracy as a tooltip when you hover over the forecast in the visualization?

Code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast);
l<-length(.arg1);
u<-.arg1[1:(l-.arg2[1])];
n<-length(u);
u[n]=.arg1[l];
jjearnts <- ts(u,frequency=24);
fcast <- forecast(jjearnts, h=.arg2[1]);
append(u,fcast$mean, after = n)",
[SaleCount],[PeriodsToForecast])
```